# Regex to split key-value pairs ignoring space in double quotes

Tags: regex, perl

My regex-fu is not as good as it should be, my apologies in advance.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;

my @AoH;
my $filename = 'metadata.txt';

open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    my $rec = {};
    for my $field ( split ) {
        (my $key, my $value) = quotewords('=', 0, $field);
        $rec->{$key} = $value;
        print "$key -> $value;\n";
    }
    push @AoH, $rec;
}
```

I want to parse the following string (located in metadata.txt):

> video_info="This is a video description" video_name="avideoname.mp4" video_thumb="avideothumbnail.jpg"

Essentially, I'd like to split the aforementioned string so that whatever is in quotes is a value (including whitespaces) and whatever is before the = is a key.

My desired output:

```
video_info -> This is a video description;
video_name -> avidenoname.mp4;
video_thumb -> avideothumbnail.jpg;
```

I'm using this as a reference to create my Array of Hashes: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch09_03.htm, with slight modifications to the code (eg. using quotewords instead of split). I feel like this is mainly a regex issue, but if there's any problems or deprecated code being used feel free to correct/explain any inconsistencies.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`split` is not suitable to split a string delimited by space into two sub-strings also containing spaces.

For example, in your case, `split` used for this line:

```
video_info="This is a video description" video_name="avideoname.mp4"
```

will give an array as following:

```
qw(video_info="This, is, a, video, description", video_name="avideoname.mp4")
```

which is definitely not the wanted output.

Instead, you could use [`quotewords`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html) to split this line:

```
quotewords('\s+', 0, $_)
```

will give:

```
qw(video_info="This is a video description", video_name="avideoname.mp4")
```

Besides, it's better to `chomp` before processing one line to remove the influence of `\n`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;

my @AoH;
my $filename = 'metadata.txt';

open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my $rec = {};
    for my $field ( quotewords('\s+', 0, $_) ) {
        (my $key, my $value) = quotewords('=', 0, $field);
        $rec->{$key} = $value;
        print "$key -> $value;\n";
    }
    push @AoH, $rec;
}
```

Comment: Detailed explanation and concise answer. Thank you.